# Crop part of a div

Tags: css, css-transforms

How do I crop the parts of the "Today" red div that are not on the special div in order to make it look like a bookmark? Desired result is shown on the second image.
Thank you!

Actual image:

[image: actual image]

Desired image:

[image: desired image]

Html:

```
<div class="panel">
  <div class="special">Special $120.00</div>
  <div class="pr2">Today</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.special {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.panel {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
  height: 70px;
}

.pr2 {
  background-color: #d13a2f;
  color: #ffffff;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  line-height: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  top: 5px;
  right: -48px;
  left: auto;
  position: absolute;
  padding-top: 20px;
  width: 140px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

[JSFiddle overlapping](https://jsfiddle.net/emiranda/Lmdb2fp0/34/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `overflow: hidden` and `position: relative` to the `.panel` div:

```
.panel {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
```

Then adjust *positioning values* to your needs.

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lmdb2fp0/37/)